# Append one or more gif animations through php

Tags: php

How to add one or more gif animations.

```
// Create image instances

$dest = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');


// Copy and merge

imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 75);


// Output and free from memory

 header('Content-Type: image/gif');
 imagegif($dest);
 imagedestroy($dest);
 imagedestroy($src);
```

The code above is not working.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/

$str = "Mary Had A Little Lamb and She LOVED It So";

echo $str = str_replace(' ','',(strtolower($str)));

exec('convert alphabets/1/a.gif -repage 92x62 -coalesce  null: ( alphabets/1/b.gif -coalesce )  -geometry +46+0 -layers Composite    out.gif');

list($width, $height) = getimagesize('alphabets/1/e.gif');

list($out_width, $out_height) = getimagesize('out.gif');

$width1 = $out_width+$width;

exec('convert out.gif -repage '.$width1.'x'.$height.' -coalesce  null: ( alphabets/1/e.gif -coalesce )  -geometry +'.$out_width.'+0 -layers Composite    out1.gif');